# Autorange a Graph that Dynamically Adds Values

Tags: java, jfreechart

I create a JFreeChart object using this method:

```
private JFreeChart createChart(XYDataset xydataset)
    {
        jfreechart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart("Server Throughtput", "Time", "Bytes/s", xydataset, true, true, false);
        XYPlot xyplot = (XYPlot) jfreechart.getPlot();
        ValueAxis valueaxis = xyplot.getDomainAxis();
        valueaxis.setAutoRange(true);
        valueaxis.setFixedAutoRange(60000D);
        valueaxis = xyplot.getRangeAxis();
        valueaxis.setRange(0.0D, 100D);

        return jfreechart;
    }
```

the graph update automatically itself.I set as max value 100D.after a while the values received go over 100D.how is it possible autorange the graph at runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `valueaxis.setRange(0.0D, 100D)` sets the auto-range flag to false.  To make the range automatically update call `valueaxis.setAutoRange(true)` after (or instead of) `valueaxis.setRange(0.0D, 100D)`

In your example you are reuseing the `valueaxis` to hold both the `DomainAxis` and `RangeAxis`.  This code auto ranges both axes:

```
        XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) result.getPlot();
        ValueAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
        domainAxis.setAutoRange(true);
        domainAxis.setFixedAutoRange(60000.0);  
        ValueAxis rangeAxis = plot.getRangeAxis();
        rangeAxis.setAutoRange(true);
```